# MATLAB Inactive Edit Text and gui background

Tags: matlab, background, callback

I added a background image to my GUI in the `OpeningFcn` function:

```
ha = axes('units','normalized','position',[0,0,1,1]);
axis off
uistack(ha, 'bottom')

bg = imread('sample.png');
imshow(bg);
set(ha, 'handlevisibility', 'off', 'visible', 'off')
```

This makes the `ButtonDownFcn` callback of an **inactive** Edit Text (its 'Enable' property is 'inactive') over the background image won't be called. That is, the inactive Edit Text won't response to mouse clicks anymore. How to solve this?

Comment: To debug, could you try setting the `ButtonDownFcn` for the axes and also the image? (`imshow` returns a handle to the image object) I wonder if one of them is capturing the mouse clicks. If that is the case, you could try moving the `uistack` call to after the `imshow` (because imshow does some funny things to the axes), or setting the `HitTest` property of the offending objects to `off`.

Comment: @user1877862 Thank you so much. I changed the code to `fig = imshow(bg); set(fig, 'HitTest', 'off');` and now it works.